# UILabel number of lines calculation returns one extra line

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am using the below UILabel extension property. UILabel line break mode is Truncate Tail. It always returns one extra line than the actual number of lines. Any thoughts on this issue.

```
var maxNumberOfLines: Int {
        guard let text = text, let font = font else {
            return 0
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let charSize = font.lineHeight
        let textSize = (text as NSString).boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: font],
            context: nil)
        let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height/charSize))
        return linesRoundedUp
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using ceil?  I suspect charSize is a little small, and in that case, the number will be over what you want, and the ceil takes it the next int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a new line character at the end of the string in my label which was contributing for the extra line. Removing that before assigning to UILabel fixed the issue.